# AS3 - Placing movie clip at specified coordinates

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, movieclip, stage

I'm making a top down shooter game as project for a college assignment in which I have very little time left to complete.

I'm trying to get the enemy movieclip to spawn off stage, I have setup a function to create a random number for the x and y position and then stored each in a var, but I cant use the two var's for the coordinates, I get 3 errors:

`Main.as, Line 33 1120: Access of undefined property enemy.`

`Main.as, Line 33 1137: Incorrect number of arguments.  Expected no more than 0.`

`Main.as, Line 34 1120: Access of undefined property enemy.`

Lines 33 - 34 Code from Main.as:

```
enemy = new Enemy(stage, xPos, yPos);
this.stage.addChild(enemy);
```

The xPos and yPos vars created on lines 18 and 19 respectively:

```
public var xPos:Number;
public var yPos:Number;
```

xPos and yPos are given values in the function spawnPos:

```
public function spawnPos()
    {
        var a:Number = Math.round(Math.random()*5);
        var aNum:Number;

        if (a <= 3)
        {
            aNum = Math.ceil(Math.random()*20) + 640;
            xPos = aNum;
            aNum = Math.ceil(Math.random()*20) + 480;
            yPos = aNum;


        }
        else if (a >= 2)
        {
            aNum = Math.ceil(Math.random()*-20) + 0;
            xPos = aNum;
            aNum = Math.ceil(Math.random()*-20) + 0;
            yPos = aNum;
        }
    }
```

And the spawnPos function is declared to run on line 32 just before the enemy is created:

```
spawnPos();
```

Help would be greatly appreciated, many thanks and hope all is having a great start to the new year. :)

Comment: 1 - You probably didn't declare the enemy variable. 2 - How many args does your constructor of Enemy accept?

Comment: 1 - I thought line 33 was declaring the enemy as a var? 2 - This question doesn't make much sense since I don't really know AS3 but we've had to make a game in it (How my lecturer expects that I do not know), but I can tell you that the enemy.as class's constructor is completley empty.

Comment: 1. Well, on line 33 you write enemy = new Enemy(...); => in as3 you always need to use the 'var' keyword, therefore it will throw you the error. It should be 'var enemy:Enemy = new Enemy(...);'. I also strongly discourage you to add the instances to the stage. Always add them to your stage-owner (either main timeline or document class). 2. The constructor is empty but you are creating an instance and passing in values => remove them: var enemy:Enemy = new Enemy();

Comment: I believe it's solved! I've made the enemy a var, then in the enemy class set the args for it to accept `xPos` and `yPos`, then moved my `spawnPos()` function to the enemy class and in it's constructor called that function. And now it works with no errors.... Thanks you guys!!! I couldn't of done it without you, thumbs up to you both :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Fixed and working

Small changes were made to both the Main.as and Enemy.as as follows:

---

**Main.as**

The changes made here were to the statement of defining the enemy. It was

> enemy = new Enemy(stage, xPos, yPos);

I removed the `stage` argument but kept the two variables `xPos` and `yPos` and made it a variable.

> var enemy:Enemy = new Enemy(xPos, yPos);

I also removed where I called the `spawnPos()` function.

---

**Enemy.as**

I moved the `spawnPos()` function from Main.as to here and called it in the constructor code so it's only run when the `enemy` varible is.

I then amended the class definition and added the arguments I wanted to be passed

> public function Enemy(xPos : Number, yPos : Number)

---

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're missing the Enemy class. Create an Enemy class with 3 arguments. Then after the line with `this.stage.addChild(enemy);` you must add:

```
enemy.x = enemy.xPos;
enemy.y = enemy.yPos;
```

I'm considering that the Enemy class extends `Sprite` or `MovieClip` class and `xPos` and `yPos` have an `get/set`.

#### edit

```
class Enemy extends Sprite 
{
    private var _xPos:Number;
    private var _yPos:Number;

    public function Enemy(/*your params here*/)
    {
        //your code here
    }

    //xPos setter
    public function set xPos(value:Number):void 
    {
        this._xPos = value;
    }

    //xPos getter
    public function get xPos():Number
    {
        return this._xPos;
    }

    //yPos setter
    public function set yPos(value:Number):void 
    {
        this._yPos = value;
    }

    //yPos getter
    public function get yPos():Number
    {
        return this._yPos;
    }
}
```

#### edit 2

If you want to store the object's position, you don't have to use `xPos` or `yPos`. Sprite and Movieclip have `x` and `y`. "Don't recreate the wheel" ;)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not too sure what you mean by `get/set`? I haven't have much experience with AS3.

Comment: About getter and setter: [link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000171.html)

Comment: Ah I think I understand what you mean by `getter/setter`. Well, I'm not trying to get the coordinates I only want to set them so the movieclip gets placed there. I have a function that will randomly generate the coordinates and puts the result into two variables `xPos` and `yPos` and because I'll be placing an array of `enemy` moiveclips on the stage it will keep changing which is why I thought I should put it in a var.

Comment: Did you create an `Enemy` class? And an enemy variable as @Fygo suggested?

Comment: I do have an enemy class, and made a change in the Main.as class for the enemy bit, I put var in front of it, which makes the enemy variably right? `var enemy:Enemy = new Enemy(xPos, yPos);`

Comment: And I think I know what the problem is, I've added 2 arguments for when placing the enemy MC on the stage (X and Y position) but I need to set what those arguments mean in the enemy class file don't I?
And in the comment above I meant `variable` not `variably`.

Comment: I believe it's solved! I've made the enemy a var, then in the enemy class set the args for it to accept `xPos` and `yPos`, then moved my `spawnPos()` function to the enemy class and in it's constructor called that function. And now it works with no errors.... Thanks you guys!!! I couldn't of done it without you, thumbs up to you both :)

Comment: Maybe you could edit your post adding the code modifications, so other people may learn with it ;)

Comment: Great idea, shall do that now :)